# Django Nested admin

Tags: nested-forms, inline-formset, django-2.2

here is my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default = '', )
    country_other_details = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default = '', null = True)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.country_name

class State(models.Model):
    in_country = models.ForeignKey(Country, related_name='in_country',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    state_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default = '')
    state_other_details = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '', null = True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.state_name

class City(models.Model):
    in_state = models.ForeignKey(State, related_name='in_state',on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length = 20, default = '')
    city_other_details = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cities"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.city_name
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms.models import inlineformset_factory
from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet

from .models import Country, State, City

from django.forms.models import BaseInlineFormSet, inlineformset_factory
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

# from publishing.utils.forms import is_empty_form, is_form_persisted

CityFormset = inlineformset_factory(State, City, extra=2,  fields=("city_name",))


class BaseStateFormset(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def add_fields(self, form, index):
        super(BaseStateFormset, self).add_fields(form, index)

        # save the formset in the 'nested' property
        form.nested = CityFormset(
            instance=form.instance,
            data=form.data if form.is_bound else None,
            files=form.files if form.is_bound else None,
            prefix='address-%s-%s' % (
                form.prefix,
                CityFormset.get_default_prefix()),
            # extra=1
        )

    def is_valid(self):
        result = super(BaseStateFormset, self).is_valid()

        if self.is_bound:
            for form in self.forms:
                if hasattr(form, 'nested'):
                    result = result and form.nested.is_valid()

        return result

    def save(self, commit=True):

        result = super(BaseStateFormset, self).save(commit=commit)

        for form in self.forms:
            if hasattr(form, 'nested'):
                if not self._should_delete_form(form):
                    form.nested.save(commit=commit)

        return result


StateFormset = inlineformset_factory(Country, State, formset=BaseStateFormset, extra=2, fields=("state_name",))
```

views.py

```
from .models import Country, State, City

def manage_state(request, parent_id):

parent = get_object_or_404(Country, id=parent_id)

if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = forms.StateFormset(request.POST, instance=parent)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        # return redirect('parent_view', parent_id=parent.id)
        return redirect(reverse('india:manage_state', kwargs={"parent_id": parent.id}))

else:
    formset = forms.StateFormset(instance=parent)

return render(request, 'home.html', {
              'parent':parent,
              'children_formset':formset})
```

What i want is a single form that will create an object to Parent(Country) model and multiple object to Child(State) as according to country's object and multiple objects to Grand Child(City) according to corresponded State

for example:

```
<form method="POST">
    Parentform:(Country)
        <input name="country_name">


        Childform:(State)
            <input name="state_name">

            GrandChildform:(City)
                <input name = "City_name">

            <button> Add GrandChild</button>

        <button> Add Child </button>

    <button>Add Parent</button>

</form>
```

also the add button should be able to add the more Countries, States and Cities dynamically to the form.

Any help, suggestions or references would be Grateful.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution. Thanks to PYTHON and Django.

As I got, We can edit our own admin using a built-in package **django-nested-admin**.

We don't require to built our Custom forms,views or anything.

I am Sharing Image of my Django-admin:
[**Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZoWw.png)

To do it I am sharing the Descriptions:

First we install a package using pip:

```
pip install django-nested-admin.
```

Now we Add the library in **settings.py**:

```
INSTALLED_APPS[
    ...

    'nested_admin',

    ...
]
```

Add the urls of the library in the **urls.py**:

```
url(r'^nested_admin/', include('nested_admin.urls')),
```

Register models in **admin.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import State, Country, City
from nested_admin import NestedModelAdmin, NestedStackedInline, NestedTabularInline


class CityTabularInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = City
    extra = 1


class StateTabularInline(NestedTabularInline):
    model = State
    extra = 1
    inlines = [CityTabularInline, ]


class CountryAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    inlines = [StateTabularInline, ]

admin.site.register(Country, CountryAdmin)
```

**Usage**:

```
NestedModelAdmin: to extend the django ModelAdmin class and to be able to use differents
types of classes in the inlines attribute.

NestedStackedInline: to allow the addition of TabularInline classes in the inlines
attribute.

NestedTabularInline: to extend the TabularInline.
```

for more details please [**Visit**](https://bedjango.com/blog/how-use-django-nested-admin/).